# javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, datetime

When I add:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to `web.xml`, then any of AJAX request in my app is disable. Why?

Do you know any equivalent for `javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE` to get same efect (set the default timezone as system timezone when a converter extending from DateTimeConverter is created)?

Comment: The issue must be in other place. Which environment are you using? Have you tried with a very basic project?

Comment: no, everything go well when i comment this at `web.xml`. I'm using TomEE 1.5 server with MyFasces 2.1, i don't try on basic project